# Why does k increment to 1 in this recursion function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running a recursion function that I got from w3schools for the page that they have on recursion, and after running the code in debug mode in vscode the k for some reason completely decrements to 0, and out of nowhere increments back up to 1. Can someone explain this to me I would much appreciate it.

### Here is the code

```
def tri_Recursion(k):
    if(k > 0):
        result = k + tri_Recursion(k-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result 


def main():
    tri_Recursion(6)
    print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest stepping through it on https://pythontutor.com/ or in a debugger.

Comment: It does not happen. Running your code, I guess 1 3 6 10 15 21.